# Refresh Tokens Google OAuth 2.0 PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Using the Google OAuth 2.0 code from this site https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

I need help coding the refresh token into the following code, I am not sure on how to do it, there are a lot of resources out there, but I can't find any that helps me incorporate it into my code. Current problem now is if I let the token expire, it gives me an error saying I don't have a refresh token and I need it because I don't want to use the force option for the accesstype. I am using the php client:

```
    //include google api files
    require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';

    //start session
    $client_id = 'xxxx';
    $client_secret = 'xxxx';
    $redirect_uri = 'xxxxx';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Backpack Em");
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2 ($client);

 if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  $client->revokeToken();   //added
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));     //redirect user back to page
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];       header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) 
  {
    //For logged in user, get details from google using access token
    $user           = $service->userinfo->get($params);
    //$user_id          = filter_var($user['id'],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $user_name          = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $first_name         = filter_var($user['given_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $last_name          = filter_var($user['family_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $email          = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $profile_url        = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $profile_image_url      = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $gender         = filter_var($user['gender'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $personMarkup       = "$email<div><img src='$profile_image_url?sz=50'></div>";
    $_SESSION['upload_token']   = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['upload_token']   = $client->getRefreshToken();

  }

else
  {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the refresh token in the session as in:

```
$refresh_token = $client->getRefreshToken();
$_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $refresh_token;
```

And when you want to get a new access token you can call:

```
$refresh_token = $_SESSION['refresh_token'];
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['upload_token'] = $access_token;
```

You can call `$client>isAccessTokenExpired()` to see if an access token has expired and you would need to trigger the refresh flow.

To print/access the `expires_in` value, you can use:

```
$json = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
echo $json['expires_in'];
```

but be aware that `expires_in` is relative to the time that the token was created, so to check if a token has expired you'd use:

```
$expired = ($json['created'] + $json['expires_in']) < time();
```

Comment: Where is the expires in command? Also does it matter where I put this in my code?

Comment: added a note on `isAccessTokenExpired`

Comment: I believe there is a command expires_in: () to tell when the refresh token expires. Do you know where this goes?

Comment: added a sample for that

Comment: Thanks, have you used this before? I am having trouble integrating it wit my code. Where do I exactly put this in my code? Also, do you know of a working demo that uses these refresh tokens?

Comment: Do you need to store the refresh token in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I hope this can still help somebody.
These are the steps I followed for a server side token refresh (no need for user to log in).

1. In a Google Developer Console app, create a new client id for OAuth, using 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground' as redirect uri.
   ( you need this for the authentication in the playground)
2. In https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, click on the settings icon in the top right corner and check "Use your own OAuth credentials". You have to insert valid credentials( client id and client secret) as generated at point 1.
3. Select and authorize your Api in the left column ("Step 1")
4. Once you got the Authorization Code, exchange it for tokens ("Step 2")
5. Now, you can use client id, client secret (the same you used at point 2) and the refresh token (the one you got at point 4 ) in your script.

This is the working code I am using (for Analytics e.g):

```
$clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // from google developer console
$clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // from google developer console
$refreshToken = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$response = $analytics->data_ga->get(
   'ga:' . xxxxxxx, 
   '7daysAgo',
   'today',
   'ga:sessions');
```

Comment: Where is this refresh token coming from? I thought the refresh tokens are generated when the users login, so it will be a unique token. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right, in my example you don't need the user to log in. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: So if I get the refresh token from the playgroud, it will automatically refresh logged in users after an hour? How long does the refresh token last?

Comment: In my application, I make a new request for an access token (through the refresh token ) when I need to call the api. As far as I know a refresh token does not expire.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly I get this refresh token from the playground? Can it just be a random refreshtoken, or does it need to be specific to my client id?